# Convert Multiple Cell Rows Into Single Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, concatenation

I am merging two Excel databases and need to ensure that some prices are the same, however, they are stored in two different ways.

To facilitate easy comparison of the tables I need to convert a table like this:

```
SKU      BREAK  PRICES
SKU-123    10   30.2
SKU-123    20   20.2
SKU-123    30   15.2
SKU-123    40   10
SKU-321    10   130.2
SKU-321    20   120.2
SKU-321    40   110
SKU-678    10   15.99
SKU-678    25   12.99
SKU-678    30   11.99
SKU-678    40   10.99
```

Into a table like this:

```
SKU          BREAK              PRICES
SKU-123      10;20;30;40        30.2;20.2;15.2;10
SKU-321      10;20;40           130.2;120.2;110
SKU-678      10;25;30;40        15.99;12.99;11.99;10.99
```

I have tried to use 'concatenate' but did not get on well with it and am stumped otherwise.

Once I have transformed this data I can then use a vlookup to compare the SKU data and find any differences, but am struggling to get to this point.

Comment: "_two databases_"... are these SQL databases? (which?) Excel spreadsheets? CSV files?

Comment: @Attie These are two excel sheets that are generated from an eccommerce platform, and an ERP. Unfortunately, both of which I have no choice over export formatting.

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 or higher then use TEXTJOIN() function. Or you may use PowerQuery - Transpose with Merge columns. And the most simple solution (for me at least) is to create own user-defined VBA array function.

Comment: @Akina I will check out text join, the VBA thing is over my head.

Comment: @Akina Text join does much the same as concatenate, but I cannot specify that it needs to only combine lines with the same sku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(";";true;IF($A$2:$A$9=D2;$B$2:$B$9;"")))
```

GoogleSheets example:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly in Google sheets. You are my new hero!