# Excel - Combining multiple cells into single cell, multiple times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a situation almost exactly the same as in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1495122/convert-multiple-cell-rows-into-single-cells?rq=1).

A simplified example of my situation. This is my source:

```
Column A       Column B
abc@email.com  Interest A
abc@email.com  Interest B
abc@email.com  Interest C
efgh@email.com Interest A
efgh@email.com Interest C
```

etc.

And it needs to look like:

```
Column A        Column B
abc@email.com   Interest A;Interest B; Interest C
efgh@email.com  Interest A;Interest C
```

etc.

The solution provided in the other thread puts me on the right track, but I have a lot of duplicates in Column B. I can't just deduplicate because there's a column C and D with specific interest breakdowns too. There are email addresses where there's literally over 200 times the same Interest in column B, with different specifications in column C and D.

So the solution from the other thread gets me part of the way there, and it's this one (executed as CSE):

```
=TEXT.JOIN(";",TRUE,IF(A:A=A2,B:B,""))
```

But that won't take out the duplicates. How do I modify the above so that it will only include unique values from Column B?

Answer (score 0):

With O365:

I used a **Table** with structured references, as the range references are then dynamic.

But you can use regular references if you prefer.

Formulas:

```
E2: =UNIQUE(tblInterest[Email])
F2: =TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,FILTER(tblInterest[Interest],tblInterest[Email]=E2))
```

and fill down

[image]

If you don't have O365 with the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions, I'd suggest using `Power Query`